# REST API for getting informations about celebrities

Tags: api

Is there any REST **API** that provides informations about "famous" people (Scientists, Writers, Philosophers, Politicians, ...) ?

In my case I need the following infos:

- Photo,
- Full Name
- Born & Died dates,
- Nationality
- Profession(s)
- Brief

Answer (score 3):

[Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page) sounds ideal for this use case.
[Here's a list of human properties the API can return](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_properties/human)
[Example Query Finding John and Sarah Connor](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Finding_John_and_Sarah_Connor)
Here's how to [Import a List of Names from Wikidata](https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/doc/datamanagement/opendata/wikidata)
This tutorial explains how to [Extract RDF Data Models from Wikidata](http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2018/11/extracting-rdf-data-models-fro.html)
[Wikidata API Call Example](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q180736&props=labels%7Cdescriptions%7Cclaims%7Csitelinks/urls&languages=az&languagefallback=&sitefilter=azwiki&formatversion=2)
[API Documentation](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=main)

API Calls pass parameters in the URL; you can see this in the example URL posted above, here:
`https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q180736&props=labels%7Cdescriptions%7Cclaims%7Csitelinks/urls&languages=az&languagefallback=&sitefilter=azwiki&formatversion=2`

Comment: Thank you but can you provide an example of how could A REST API request look like !

Comment: That was not what you asked, and now I'm torn because I do want to help you but it feels like you are not trying at all. What have you done to accomplish this?

Comment: I tried a lot, I find Wikidata before your valuable answer, but until now I can't understand where in the Wikidata website I can find a simple explanation/example of rest url, that retrieves the data I need .. all I see lot of talk about SPARQL & RDF that I hadn't heard about them before !

Comment: gotcha. ok, well that maybe because they use mediawiki's API, i bet that is what its referred to as.